# PHPMailer send email using Gmail Oauth2

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, gmail, phpmailer

Pretty straightforward. I have my Gmail oauth2 access_token. How can I use PHPMailer to send emails?

(I do not have SMTP credentials)

Answer (score 2):

PHPMailer supports Google's OAuth2 authentication from version 5.2.11; follow [this guide](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Using-Gmail-with-XOAUTH2).

The next version of PHPMailer ([6.0](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/tree/6.0)) has substantially revised OAuth2 support that will work with many more services.

Comment: Note that PHPMailer now requires you to install several dependencies for OAuth2 support and this requires the extremely bloated composer dependency stack.

Comment: Rubbish. Composer is not bloated at all. It's entirely possible to end up with excessive numbers of dependencies, but that's not composer's fault. Pretty much all PHP frameworks (nearly all of which are based on composer) have been getting smaller. Probably the best example of this is Symfony, which went from a 24Mb skeleton app to about 280kb, all by using composer more efficiently. An empty composer project is 48k.